# Macro to document LaTeX command with index

Tags: macros, indexing

I am writing a document, to explain LaTeX usage.  Obviously, this document contains a lot of LaTeX commands.

I defined a macro, that will take one argument (the command name) and print it in typewriterfont.  To make life easy, I thought it a clever idea, to let the macro add the backslash.  This works fine for me:

[image: Sample text output with backslashed-commands]

Years later, I thought the time has come to add an index to the document.  I added the `\index` command into my macro.  This is how I did it:

```latex
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{%
  \cmd@font{\textbackslash#1}%
  % Don't forget to reset the font!
  \normalfont\selectfont%
  % Insert the command to the index, but preserve the backslash
  \def\@cmd{#1}
  \index{#1@\texttt{\@cmd}}%
}%
```

This works quite sufficent, the only drawback is, that the index just lists the pure command name without the backslash.  Stupid me wasn't able, to think of a clever way, to add the backslash.

Here you can see the index:

[image: Index without backslashes]

If I change my macro by adding a backslash to the index argument, like this

```latex
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{%
  \cmd@font{\textbackslash#1}%
  % Don't forget to reset the font!
  \normalfont\selectfont%
  % Insert the command to the index, but preserve the backslash
  \def\@cmd{\#1}
  \index{#1@\texttt{\@cmd}}%
}%
```

it won't print the backslash, but the `#1`.  Here is a sample picture of the desaster :-)

[image: Index desaster with hashes]

What should be a clever way to implement this feature?

This is the obvious MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\cmd@font{\normalfont\ttfamily\selectfont}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{%
  \cmd@font{\textbackslash#1}%
  % Don't forget to reset the font!
  \normalfont\selectfont%
  % Insert the command to the index, but preserve the backslash
  \def\@cmd{#1}
  \index{#1@\texttt{\@cmd}}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Command \cmd{index} will be used to create a word in the index file,
while \cmd{printindex} will will print the sorted index.

\printindex{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\textbackslash`. Using this in your MWe produces the index:

[image]

Here is your modified MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\cmd@font{\normalfont\ttfamily\selectfont}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{%
  \cmd@font{\textbackslash#1}%
  % Don't forget to reset the font!
  \normalfont\selectfont%
  % Insert the command to the index, but preserve the backslash
  \def\@cmd{#1}
  \index{#1@\texttt{\textbackslash\@cmd}}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Command \cmd{index} will be used to create a word in the index file,
while \cmd{printindex} will will print the sorted index.

\printindex{}
\end{document}
```

Btw, you might want to switch to using [imakeidx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx). It works pretty much exactly the same, via `\usepackage{imakeidx}`, but with a number of improvements such as automatic index compilation.

Comment: Thank you.  Didn't thought, it was that easy.

Comment: @Jan It's often the case tat you just need to know some (obscure) command:) Glad it helped.